# C# ZipFile when downloaded on mac, shows file paths instead of folders

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-4.0, zip

On windows the folders are all there correctly but on mac I get the following:

[image]

All I'm using to create the zip folder is

> ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()

Which is working good to do what I need. The folder that is getting zipped has all folders and directories correct also, only when I move to mac does it get messed up.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the implementation. Can you upgrade to at least .NET 4.6.1? Microsoft changed the path separator from a backslash to a slash in order to fix the issue and also made it configurable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712573(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396